# Is it possible to target a specific nav on your page?

Tags: html, css, modx

I've got a page that's going to contain multiple nav's (this is being handeled by the cms called ModX but it should be the same for any). The header nav is just to navigate across the site as most sites have. Now my client wanted a dropdown on multiple elements (seperate from the main menu). Now is my question can i style those nav's in specific? and what about the child's?

if i want tot target the second

for example would it be possible to do:

```
.nav_name_1 li ul li{ some awesome styling }
.nav_name_2 li ul li{ more awesome styles }
```

I'll add the ModX tag since there might be a snippet that takes care of this.

**Edit**

```
    <section id="main" role="main">

        <div id="slider">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns nopad">
      <div class="slidercontainer">
        <ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-auto-height="calc" data-cycle-slides="> li" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-next=".slidercontainer .next" data-cycle-prev=".slidercontainer .prev" data-cycle-swipe="true" data-cycle-log="false" style="position: relative;"><li class="cycle-sentinel cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; opacity: 1; visibility: hidden; display: block;">
  <img src="/i/slide/Slidewb.jpg" alt="Weidse Blik" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <div class="text hide-for-small" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <h2 style="visibility: hidden;"></h2>
    <p style="visibility: hidden;"></p>

  </div>               
</li>

        <li class="cycle-slide cycle-slide-active" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; opacity: 1;">
  <img src="/i/slide/Slidewb.jpg" alt="Weidse Blik">
  <div class="text hide-for-small">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>

  </div>               
</li></ul>
        <div class="controls hide-for-touch">
          <a href="#" class="prev control" title="vorige slide"></a>
          <a href="#" class="next control" title="volgende slide"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text show-for-small">
        <h2>Weidse Blik </h2>
        <p>Uw partner in agrarisch ondernemen!</p>
        <a href="diensten" class="cta" title="Bekijk onze diensten">Bekijk onze diensten</a>
      </div>              
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

        <div class="tagline hide-for-small">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns hide-for-small">
              Uw partner in agrarisch ondernemen!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="services">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
              <ul class="small-block-grid-1 large-block-grid-4">
                <li>

<div class="icon">
 <a href="producten/producten" title="Kunsmest">
<img src="/i/overview/Fotolia_45201390_XS.jpg" alt="Kunstmest">
 </a>
</div>


  <div class="text">
    <h2>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="producten/producten" title="Kunsmest">
             Kunsmest
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</h2>
    <p>

</p>
<a href="producten/producten" class="more" title="Kunsmest">Meer over Kunsmest</a>
  </div>                  

</li>
<li>

<div class="icon">
 <a href="producten/zaden" title="Zaden">
<img src="/i/overview/zadenwb.png" alt="Zaden">
 </a>
</div>


  <div class="text">
    <h2>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="producten/zaden" title="Zaden">
             Zaden
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</h2>
    <p>

</p>
<a href="producten/zaden" class="more" title="Zaden">Meer over Zaden</a>
  </div>                  

</li>
<li>

<div class="icon">
 <a href="producten/handelsartikelen" title="Handelsartikelen">
<img src="/i/overview/artikelenwb.png" alt="Handelsart">
 </a>
</div>


  <div class="text">
    <h2>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="producten/handelsartikelen" title="Handelsartikelen">
             Handelsartikelen
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</h2>
    <p>

</p>
<a href="producten/handelsartikelen" class="more" title="Handelsartikelen">Meer over Handelsartikelen</a>
  </div>                  

</li>
<li>

<div class="icon">
 <a href="producten/veevoer/" title="Veevoer">
<img src="/i/overview/veevoerwb.png" alt="Veevoer">
 </a>
</div>


  <div class="text">
    <h2>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="producten/veevoer/" title="Veevoer">
             Veevoer
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</h2>
    <p>

</p>
<a href="producten/veevoer/" class="more" title="Veevoer">Meer over Veevoer</a>
  </div>                  

</li>
<li>


  <div class="text">
    <h2>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="diensten" title="Diensten">
             Diensten
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</h2>
    <p>

</p>
<a href="diensten" class="more" title="Diensten">Meer over Diensten</a>
  </div>                  

</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>







        <div id="twitter">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-12 columns nopad">
      <ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-auto-height="calc" data-cycle-slides="> li" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-swipe="true" data-cycle-log="false">
        <strong>TwitterX Error:</strong> Could not load TwitterX as required values were not passed.
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




        <div id="information">
          <div class="row">            

            <div class="small-6 large-6 columns nopad info">
              <div class="picture">
                <a href="" title="">
                  <img src="/i/info/WBinfo.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                <h3><a href="" title="">Informatie</a></h3>
                <div class="content hide-for-small">
                  <p><span>&nbsp;<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat mass</span></span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="small-6 large-6 columns nopad info">
              <div class="picture">
                <a href="" title="">
                  <img src="/i/info/WBinfo.png" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                <h3><a href="" title="">Informatie</a></h3>
                <div class="content hide-for-small">
                  <p><span>&nbsp;<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat mass</span></span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        

        <div class="references">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 small-12 columns nopad">       
      <ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-auto-height="calc" data-cycle-slides="> li" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-next=".references .next" data-cycle-prev=".references .prev" data-cycle-swipe="true">

      </ul>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





      </section>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: I can but there is going to be ModX code in there.

Comment: just show view source page Or copy it from inspect element window

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is possible to target and style different nav elements using different class (or id) selectors exactly as you have suggested. Have you tried it?